# iPad photo editing app that exports edits as XMP to reuse in lightroom?

Tags: photos, adobe-lightroom

Basically, I'm looking for Lightroom for iPad :) but until then, I'm trying to find an alternative.

To organize and tag pictures I'll be using Photosmith which integrates with Lightroom.

Now, I need an app to do basic editing of pictures (cropping, exposure, saturation). But I need an app will do this in a non-destructive way and that will make the edits available as XMP so that later, I can just copy the XMP as sidecar files and load them in Lightroom (or better, it could load them via a lightroom plug-in the same way Photosmith works).

PS: I posted the same question on photo.stackexchange.com, see [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21663/ipad-photo-editing-app-that-exports-edits-as-xmp-to-reuse-in-lightroom).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Adobe Revel](http://www.adobe.com/products/revel.html)?

Basically you can edit photos on your iPad, store them on your computer and the edit them there as well.

It's a subscription service with many of the features of Lightroom.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However, it seems like Revel is more of an alternative to Lightroom then a way to extend it on a mobile device. Integration with my actual Lightroom library is required. Also, Revel does not support RAW files and there's no software for Windows.